# Difference between null=True and on_delete=models.SET_NULL django

Tags: python, django

I have a field

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

What is the difference between these two attributes on model field ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`null=True` means owner field can be `null` in the database which means you can make an object of your model that has no owner. 
`on_delete=models.SET_NULL`
means if the owner of an existing object got deleted set this field for existing object to null.

Answer (score 4):

SET_NULL argument of the ForeignKey on_delete option is only available to you when you have set the null option on the ForeignKey field to True.

After use null=True and on_delete=models.SET_NULL, when a deletion happens to the referenced object then the value of the referencing object will be updated as NULL. So a NULL value will be placed for the referencing object.

Answer (score 2):

`null=True` means that the field could be empty or null, but `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` is being used to take of the presence of the owner of the field, that it should be set to NULL if the owner is not present.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28557737)

Comment: @Andreus In what way is this a comment?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This is one of a handful of standard comments available in the review system. It was probably not the correct comment; my apologies, Manas. A more apropos comment would be: This seems like an edit to the existing answer, and not a new answer.

Comment: @Andreus It looks like an answer in itself to me.